# Getting an XML element value from a string without using simplexml_load_file

Tags: php, xml

I don't want to use `simplexml_load_file` function in my php script, but I have a line from the XML file from a server through the `fsockopen`, `fwrite` and `fgets` functions.

How can I get an XML element value from the string (line) which I have got?

```
$fs = fsockopen("website", 80);
if (!$fs) {
    echo "$errstr ($errno)<br />\n";
} else {
    fwrite($fs, $req.$bdy);
    while(!feof($fs)) {
       $GLOBALS['s'] = fgets($fs);
    }
}
fclose($fs);
$attr = $GLOBALS['s']->attributes();  // THIS DOES NOT WORK
echo $attr['Day date']; // I CANNOT GET VALUE HERE
```

Comment: can u share the xml line and what attribute you want to get?

Comment: `$GLOBALS['s']` is just a string. Use DOMDocument to parse it.

Comment: @Orchidea have you checked [`simplexml_load_string()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php)?

Answer (score 0):

If it is a string then you can use the regular expression to get the attribute value. From question I presume that you need "Date" attribute. To get it you can use simple regular expression to get the values. Refer my below code,

```
$fs = fsockopen("website", 80);
if (!$fs) {
    echo "$errstr ($errno)<br />\n";
} else {
    fwrite($fs, $req.$bdy);
    while(!feof($fs)) {
       $GLOBALS['s'] = fgets($fs);
    }
}
fclose($fs);
// to get the matched attribute
preg_match('/date\=\\"(.*?)\"/', $GLOBALS['s'], $output_array);
var_dump($output_array[1]);
```

Comment: This solution is working --- I think,  I can get all attributes in this way from the string. Thank you!